# Can JavaScript be used to send and store information on a server?

Tags: javascript, database, data-retrieval

For example: When you ask a question on stackoverflow, you input information into the text box, and that information is sent to the server where it is stored and displayed to the end-user.

Can the process of sending this information, and retrieving/displaying it be written in JS?
If yes, is it a good language to do so or are there more efficient ones?
If no, what is this process usually written in?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use AJAX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to send and receive information from a server.

Comment: Note: You can also use HTML for that, there is no need for any programming language at all for that part of an application.

Comment: partially true. You can do certain things with pure html, but to do a server request without requiring a full page load, you need to use JS. Also, technically, HTML is a programming language

Comment: No, it's not partially true, it's just true. What the op asks for can be done in plain HTML, there is no need to do a partial load. Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language "Markup languages like XML, HTML or troff, which define structured data, are not generally considered programming languages."

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ajax calls` to do any server side methods. Please check the [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

[edit removed irrelevant response after re-reading original question...]

As far as javascript's role, it's called a client-side language because it really just lives in the client's browser, and not on the server. It is a very nifty tool for keeping an eye on what the user is doing in the browser, packaging up data, and firing it off to send to the server. That's when the server-side languages would take over, process the data, and send a response back to the client's browser. Usually, the client's browser receives the server responses, but javascript is also capable of receiving server responses, which is usually called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).

It's a very broad subject, but I appreciate that you have to start somewhere to know what more specific questions to ask. Hope this helps.